# Exporting sheet as csv

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to export a sheet from my Excel file as a csv.

I am getting the error

> Method SaveAs of Object Workbook Failed`

on my `SaveAs` line.

I notice as this code creates a new workbook, it has several blank default sheet tabs, would this be causing the issue?

```vb
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
    
    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
    
    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Load check data")     'Sheet to export as CSV
    Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Possibly overwrite without asking
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B15") & "estload_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("F1") & ".csv"
    Debug.Print Path
    wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=Path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

**Edit to exclude WbkExport variable, replace with ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook.**

```vb
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
    
    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
    Dim Path As String
    
    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Load check data")     'Sheet to export as CSV
    'Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Possibly overwrite without asking
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B15") & "estload_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("F1") & ".csv"
    Debug.Print Path
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=Path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Side note: you don't need to actually create a workbook. `shtToExport.Copy` with no parameters will create a new workbook, which will then be the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: So you're saying I can eliminate this line and get the same result?

Comment: Yes you can eliminate `Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add` and just do `shtToExport.Copy`, and then work with `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Tried this, now I seem to be getting `application-defined or object defined error`. I updated the code above if you want to take a look.

Comment: Should just be `shtToExport.Copy`. No `Before`. Then `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`.

Comment: But will this save the sheet as a separate file?

Comment: Yes. `shtToExport.Copy` by itself creates a new workbook.

Comment: Thanks. But still getting application defined error on my ActiveSheet Save As line.

Comment: Probably means your path is invalid.

Comment: Thank you BIGBEN!

Answer (score 1):

The previous comments are correct. A simple procedure would be:

```
    Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()
    
    'Simple copy of sheet content as csv file
    Dim NameSheet As String
    Dim PathNameCsv As Variant
           
    'Change names & Output Path
    NameSheet = "MySheet"
    PathNameCsv = "D:\Documents\MyCsv"
    
    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NameSheet)     'Sheet to export as CSV
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Possibly overwrite without asking
    shtToExport.SaveAs Filename:=PathNameCsv, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'When saving the sheet as csv, _
    'by default its name is changed to the name of the csv.
    'Here you restore your name
    With shtToExport
    .Name = NameSheet '
    End With
  
End Sub
```